# Delete currently selected bound combobox item and then have it select nothing?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

How can I make a combobox select nothing (ie. `SelectedIndex = -1`) after deleting the bound item that was currently selected.  I don't like how the next item gets selected  after the currently selected item gets deleted.  This could lead to some problems with the wrong value being selected.  Would be ideal if there was a way to add this behaviour directly to an inherited combobox.

Comment: There's a much simpler solution. Just invert the problem and set `SelectedIndex = -1` *before* deleting the bound item that is currently selected.

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work when the last item is the currently selected item.  The next to last item ends up getting selected.

Comment: try posting some code with regards to your ComboBox and its events.

Comment: My bad, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx), "You cannot set the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox item to -1 if the item is a data-bound item." Apparently this is a [known bug](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;327244), but the workaround (as mentioned) is to set the property to "-1" twice in a row. Maybe someone who is more of a databinding expert than myself can provide a more elegant solution.

Comment: I tried the SelectedIndex = 0, then SelectedIndex = -1 workaround  and it appears to be working now. Testing it further ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the known bug link posted by Cody Gray, the workaround is to do:

```
SelectedIndex = 0
SelectedIndex = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I also like the suggestion made by @Cody Gray in the comments. However, I thought about this and another way you might be able to do this is by attaching an Event which fires when you remove an item from the ComboBox. Set the `SelectedIndex = -1` in that event handler. Now, I am not sure if there is such a readily available event, so it might be worthwhile to look into it.

Comment: I assumed the problem was he has some other event firing when the selected item gets changed. If the currently selected data-bound item gets removed, presumably the selection rolls up/down to the next data-bound item in the list, causing something undesirable to happen. If not, there'd be no reason to ask the question. You could just write two lines of code, one to remove the item and one to set `SelectedIndex = -1`.